# App and MySQL Docker containers are linked together with docker-compose. How do I connect to MySQL container database with JDBC url from my app?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have two Docker containers linked together using docker-compose. The first one is my app Docker container. The second one is MySQL container.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1' 
services:
db:
image: mysql:latest
environment:
  - 'MYSQL_USER=root'
  - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=claytablet-pw'
ports:
  - '3306:3306'    
restart: always
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: claytablet-pw
  aem63:
image: pulse/prepared-aem-6.3.1.1:3
restart: always
depends_on:
  - 'db'    
ports:
  - '4502:4502'
links:
  - 'db:db'
```

I've created a database inside my MySQL container. Now I need to connect to it with JDBC url inside my app container. What port should be used instead of ? jdbc:mysql://?:3306/claytabletdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `db:3306` inside your app container.

For more information, take a look at documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks. 

 I've also found out that I can use Networks/IPAddress of this container which I can get using docker inspect container_name command.

Comment: @AnthonyMofo, I'm glad to hear you find the answer useful. It would be great if you could mark the answer as "accepted". Thus, other users can find the solution.